# raphael js проблемма избыточного кода svg в path

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Оптимизированный код svg библиотека raphaeljs раздувает до 10 и более знаков после точки. Т.е. начинаю работать с обычным svg path в raphael типа -  "m 278.886,109.831 c -2.421,0.507 -5.608,0.928 и.т.д." когда смотрю изображение через инспектор браузера он преобразуется в нечто подобное - "278.886,109.831C276.46500000000003,110.33800000000001". Есть ли возможность исправить? Думаю это должно  влиять на производительность анимации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная погрешность возникает из-за использования стандарта IEEE 754 для представления чисел с плавающей точкой. На производительности это никак не отражается.

[Описание стандарта IEEE 754 на Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)
[Неточные вычисления в javascript](https://learn.javascript.ru/number#%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Данный пример наглядно демонстрирует неточность в представлении чисел с плавающей точкой:

```js
$('#result').html(0.1 + 0.2)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```